# Display an icon based on active theme

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to load the right icon based on active light or dark theme.

`<NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" tap="{{ showSlideout }}" />`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will use icon `ic_menu` or `ic_menu2` based on `is_dark` variable's  `true/false` value which can be changed somewhere as part of bindingContext observable

```
<NavigationButton icon="{{is_dark? 'res://ic_menu':'res://ic_menu2'}}" tap="{{ showSlideout }}" />
```

and if that won't work try this way, where you will bind variable for use in expression

```
<NavigationButton icon="{{is_dark , is_dark? 'res://ic_menu':'res://ic_menu2'}}" tap="{{ showSlideout }}" />
```